# fileatime() showing inacurate results

Tags: php

I am trying to check a time in which a specific file was accessed, so I tried to go with checking the date first.

```
var_dump(date('d', fileatime('clientNames.txt'))); 
//string '13' (length=2)
```

Now, normally the date in which the file was accessed/changed should be shown, but instead I see `13` even in the file properties, `Nov 13`. That was the time when the file was created, but I have modified it many times after than, however `fileatime()` always gives creation date.

I even tried to clear the cache `clearstatcache();` still it shows `13`

Comment: On what operating system and file system is this? Are you seeing the correct "last modified" date elsewhere?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am using windows, and Yes. I can see the last modified date being today, which is correct. even `date('d')` shows today's date. So, I am thinking the function is buggy??

Comment: Strange, I can see no mention on the 'net that this doesn't work on Windows. Have you tried `filemtime()`? (If you want the "last changed" time that is more relevant anyway)

Comment: Some operating systems have an option to disable access time tracking on a particular filesystem, for the sake of I/O efficiency.  Perhaps that's enabled for the filesystem you're working with?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry for the delay. `filemtime()` works, but `fileatime()` still does not work. As Jim pointed out, this may be some file permission issue. But for now, I am using `fileatime()` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call:

```
clearstatcache();
```

before `fileatime()`. [Function manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

Comment: I tried it, but still does not work. This is windows problem now. But, `filemtime()` works just fine for now.